# Calling modifiers of a deque by reference in a function produce MinGW64 compile errors

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, c++11, deque

I'm passing a variable `std::deque<cv::Point[4]> pastpolygons` by reference.  I'm also passing the C array `cv::Point polygon[4]` by reference to the same function.  The intention is that the one function may push/pop the array into the `deque` of arrays as needed.  I've written the code how I think it should work ( is there any other way to write code? ) and the compile errors are pretty verbose and hard to understand (it's several pages).

Here's the code:

```
void AveragePolygon ( cv::Point (*polygon)[4], std::deque<cv::Point[4]> *pastpolygons, int samplestokeep )
{
    //FIFO
    pastpolygons->push_back( *polygon );   //comment and compiles fine
    if ( pastpolygons->size() > samplestokeep ) {
        pastpolygons->pop_front();         //comment and compiles fine
    }
    return;
}
```

The parameter and argument syntax was particularly tricky, but it compiles so long as I don't try to call the modifiers of `pastpolygons`.  I've also tried `(*pastpolygons).push_back/pop_front` instead, to no avail.  Any ideas?

Also, the first bit of the compile errors:

```
C:/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = cv::Point_<int> [4]; _Args = {const cv::Point_<int> (&)[4]}; _Tp = cv::Point_<int> [4]]': C:/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:256:4:   required from 'static std::_Require<typename std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = cv::Point_<int> [4]; _Args = {const cv::Point_<int> (&)[4]}; _Alloc = std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> [4]>; std::_Require<typename s
```

Comment: "I'm passing a variable "std::deque pastpolygons" by reference." - no, you are not.

Comment: You can't store arrays in the standard containers. You can use `std::vector` or `std::array`. And those are pointers, not references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel the need to say
that when you are on C++, and especially nowadays c++11
you can forget about pointers, and rock it using 
high level programming! (which is super efficient! 
That's the beauty of C++).

So to our busyness, I would define a polygon to be:

```
typedef vector<cv::Point> Polygon;
```

And then comes the rest:

```
void AveragePolygons(Polygon polygon, deque<Polygon> &pastpolygons)
{
    pastpolygons.push_back(polygon);   //comment and compiles fine
    if (pastpolygons.size() > samplestokeep ) {
        pastpolygons.pop_front();         //comment and compiles fine
    }
}
```

When working like this, 
I believe the problems you experience will be gone,
since many of them relate to pointers, shallow copying, etc..

**One more** thing, 
if you want to make sure a polygon consists of 4 points only
you can derive it from a `vector` and provide the proper 
constructor or other member functions to ensure this.

For example, the following obsessively-c++11 code
defines a constructor which takes 4 points:

```
struct Polygon : public vector<cv::Point> {
    Polygon(cv::Point p1, cv::Point p2, cv::Point p3, cv::Point p4) :
        vector<cv::Point>{p1, p2, p3, p4}  
    {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, limiting the the array to 4 points was my intention and reason for using c-style arrays over std::vector, the method to limit the vector to 4 points by constructor was helpful.

Comment: You should use std::array then.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Always learning new stuff here at SO... :-)